# Issue with scraping a list to get href using Goutte and PHP

Tags: php, web-scraping, goutte

I am trying to scrape the following, I basically want the text and the link, I am using [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) with PHP. I can get the text fine using the following code but I cannot get the href value. Any help would be amazing.

```
$crawler->filter('#most-popular > div > ol > li > a')->each(function ($node) {
    var_dump($node->getAttribute('href'));
});


<li class="first-child ol1">
  <a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-south-yorkshire-31895703" class="story">
    <span class="livestats-icon livestats-1">1: </span>MP claims £17 poppy wreath expenses</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The bellow code will fix this issue.

```
$crawler->filter('#most-popular > div.panel.open > ol > li.first-child.ol1 > a')->each(function ($node) {
    $href = $node->extract(array('href'));
    var_dump($href[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 20):

[`getAttribute()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) is implemented as [`attr()`](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html#method_attr) within the [`Crawler`](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html) class.

```
$crawler->filter('#most-popular > div.panel.open > ol > li.first-child.ol1 > a')->each(function ($node) {
    var_dump($node->attr('href'));
});
```